# Merging Multiple JP2 image files on QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, merge, gdal-merge

I have about 150 Images that I need to merge together.  I have tried to go about this by using the GDAL misc > merge tool but it is too much for QGIS to handle with even 20 images at a time.  I was wondering if there was a different way to go about this. The image layers I am using are Multi-band not singleband layers.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The file size and extents might get huge. I would not recommend doing it in the first place.

Comment: @RoVo Ultimately I need an aerial view for a 25 mile stretch of land split up into 4 sections.  I will split it up after I get the one big image because that would be the easiest way for me.  I can use another command to compress the size of the image down once I get them all merged.

Comment: @Joseph I got your way to work it seems like now after Save-as on the VRT to make it into a TIFF.  Thank You.

Comment: @Jhunt9 - Most welcome, glad it helped! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could build a **virtual raster** which allows you to merge multiband rasters. This should be less memory-intensive than the `gdal_merge` tool. You can access this from the same menu:

```
Raster > Miscellaneous > Build Virtual Raster (Catalog)
```